# Change icons when toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've this code

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    //After it toggle the content with this button
    $('.content_toggle').hide();
    $('.link-toggle').before('<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>');

    $(".link-toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).next(".project .content_toggle").slideToggle("slow");
        $('.project').find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');
    });
    //Let's the magic applies <3
});
```

```css
i, h4 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="project">
    <h4 class="link-toggle">Link 1</h4>

    <div id="" class="content_toggle">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="project">
    <h4 class="link-toggle">Link 2</h4>

    <div id="" class="content_toggle">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It almost works, but when I click on a link, all the icons change.

I want that when I click on the first link for example, only its icon change.
The same thing when I click on the second link, only its icon change.

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 4):

Grab the current element with `$(this)` and navigate up to the parent with [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(this).closest('.project').find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');
```

```js
jQuery(function ($) {


   //After it toggle the content with this button
   $('.content_toggle').hide();
   $('.link-toggle').before('<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>');

   $(".link-toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).next(".project .content_toggle").slideToggle("slow");

     $(this).closest('.project').find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');
   });

   //Let's the magic applies <3
  });
```

```css
i, h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="project">
 <h4 class="link-toggle">Link 1</h4>
 <div id="" class="content_toggle"><p>Hello world</p></div>
</div>



<div class="project">
  <h4 class="link-toggle">Link 2</h4>
  <div id="" class="content_toggle"><p>Hello world</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beat you by 40 seconds my evil twin :)

Comment: @Satpal, actually, 6 seconds according to my page :) Oh well, you still beat me!

Answer (score 3):

You are toggling the class of all `i`, You need to toggle the class taking current element in context. So you can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to navigate to element with `project` class.

Use

```
$(this).closest('.project').find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');
```

instead of

```
$('.project').find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {


  //After it toggle the content with this button
  $('.content_toggle').hide();
  $('.link-toggle').before('<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>');

  $(".link-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).next(".project .content_toggle").slideToggle("slow");

    $(this).closest('.project').find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');
  });


});
```

```css
i,
h4 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="project">
  <h4 class="link-toggle">Link 1</h4>
  <div id="" class="content_toggle">
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="project">
  <h4 class="link-toggle">Link 2</h4>
  <div id="" class="content_toggle">
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>
</div>
```